# SQL query using replace a value in one table by randomly selecting a value in another table

Tags: php, sql, random

I have a table with an value that I would like to be updated periodically with a cron job.  However, I need to update the value by replacing it with a value from a different table.  The issue is that I would like the replacement value to be chosen randomly.

For example, Table 1 has

```
ID    Email
=================
1     bobatumail
```

Table 2 has:

```
ID    Email
================
1     bobatumail
2     joeatumail
3     peteatumail
4     biffatumail
5     wilneratumail
6     wilsonatumail
```

I would like the query to replace bobatumail in Table 1 with any of the other values in Table 2 as long as it is random.  It could even be the same value as in Table 1.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: why do you have 2 tables with identical structure? what's the big picture? what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: The structures are not identical.  I just abridged it for simplicity...   The user in Table 1 receives special benefits, and I want the other users in Table 2 to have a chance to receive the same benefit over time.  They can only receive the benefit if they are placed in Table 1.  Table 1 is a one row table.

Comment: Will the random values always be picked from the same column in table 2?

Comment: sounds like you should just have a column in table 2 (int 0\1) "special_benefit" rather than 2 tables.

Comment: @ Onite, yes.  @ Dagon, I cannot make that change, but I understand your point...  I mis-wrote earlier, table 1 has many rows, and it has to remain in place...

Comment: What sort of database are you using? MySQL? Sqlserver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL you could use the REPLACE statement:

```
REPLACE INTO table1 (ID, Email)
SELECT 1, table2.Email FROM table2 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
```

The "1" in the second line represents the id of the entry while the second part returns a random value out of table2. Yes, there are solutions using the UPDATE statement (JOIN and ANSI) but its always tricky and you usually have to turn off safe update mode.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_safe-updates

Please note that REPLACE first deletes the old entry and then reinserts the new one.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replace.html

Comment: Select 1 is the ID of the entry in Table 1?  I used the syntax, but am receiving an unknown column error in field list (for the Select 1 part of the syntax)...

Comment: Perhaps the column names are misspelled: Replace 'id' with 'ID' and 'email' with 'Email'. I corrected it in the statement.

Comment: Yes, 1 is the ID of the entry in table1.

Comment: Does it matter that in my example, I left out some column headers for simplicity.  For example, the real headers in Table 1 are (settingid,name,value,accountid) where value is "email" and setting ID is "ID"...  I have the exact names for the columns and row name, but keep getting an error.  It is actually saying the Select 1 is a column error not a row

Comment: Ok, which database are you using?

Comment: Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
    Server version: 5.5.23-55
    Protocol version: 10
    MySQL charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

Comment: In order to execute the query with multiple columns you have to join them in the subselect and add them to the update/replace statement.:

REPLACE INTO table1 (settingid, value, name, accountid)
SELECT 1, table2.value, table1B.name, table1B.accountid
FROM table2 
JOIN table1 AS table1B ON table1B.settingid = 1 /* again the id of the entry */
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;

But it is really strange that you cannot execute the SELECT as a standalone query. Whats exactly the error code? Btw. your MySQL version should support this.

Comment: here is the error:  #1054 - Unknown column '9038fa14' in 'field list'   '9038fa14' is my 1

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know which 1 you replaced. Can you please post your total query.

Comment: REPLACE INTO qu_g_settings (settingid, name, value, accountid) 
SELECT 9038fa14, qu_pap_users.refid FROM  qu_pap_users ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;

Comment: Rudi, I accepted the answer.  By example used only a numeric value for the ID, but it included alpha characters, so I needed to add single quotes.  Thanks!